# Python: How to gain more control while using 'for' loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have got the following piece of code, so that while any exception occurs, re-do this loop, instead of jumping to the next loop. Please note the pseudo code here does work as intended:

```
for cl in range(0, 10):
    try:
        some_function(cl)
    except :
        cl -= 1
```

My initiative was that once something go wrong, do it again. Obviously, this is not a working idea. So given the assumption that the `for` loop and `range function` being used, how to implement the control that I described?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `some_function()` will eventually succeed? Because otherwise, you will have an infinite loop.

Comment: @KyleStrand No, not sure. But outside of this code, there is a timer to ping an alert program at a frequent rate, once it has not get pinged for a timeout period of time, it will shoot an alert. For simplicity, I didn't mentioned. But thanks all the same for pointing out that.

Comment: It's a really bad sign you are iterating over a range. Do you actually want numbers or are you using them as indices, if it's the latter, it's not Pythonic and there is a better way. Likewise, `except` should only be used with specific exceptions, as otherwise you are likely to catch things you don't mean to and obscure bugs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply need a second loop inside the first to continue trying the function until it works:

```
for cl in range(0, 10):
    while True:
        try:
            some_function(cl)
        except Exception:
            continue    # try it again
        else:
            break       # exit inner loop, continue to next c1
```

Comment: I much prefer this since it also works with "real" Python `for` loops that iterate over a sequence of objects directly.

Comment: Agreed. Also, if, upon failure, `some_function()` merely returned `False` instead of throwing an exception, you could simplify this code and replace the `while True:` with the line `while not some_function(cl): pass`.

Comment: @kindall Out of curiosity, is it redundant to have that 'else' keyword? Why not directly break?

Comment: I like being explicit, but you could indeed break after the `try/except`, or even inside the `try` block itself, after the function call.

Comment: I believe it's not redundant in this case, but it would **not** be redundant if the `except` clause didn't force a `continue`.

Comment: Even more explicit: `break` belongs in the `try` clause, right after the call to `some_function()`: Call the function and break out, unless something goes wrong. (`try: somefunction(c1); break; except ...`)

Comment: I find the `else:` block to be more explicit, whereas having a statement inside `try:` when you don't want to catch exceptions in it but merely want to execute it after the statement you want to catch is less so. Of course, `break` can't throw an exception anyway, so...

Answer (score 4):

For more control over the loop variable, you might want to use a `while` loop:

```
cl = 0
while cl < 10:
    try:
        some_function(cl)
        cl += 1
    except:
        pass
```

In Python, the `pass` statement is a "do-nothing" placeholder. In the case where you get an exception, the same `cl` value will be tried again.

Of course, you will also want to add some mechanism where you can exit the loop if you *always* get an exception.

Comment: I know this is demo code, but you should also encourage catching *specific* exception types. Other than that, great post.

Comment: @ThaneBrimhall: That's a good point. Catching all exceptions with `except:` makes it difficult to exit the program with Ctrl+C.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Nope, `KeyboardInterrupt` [isn't caught by a bare `except:`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) because it inherits from `BaseException` directly.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Good to know, thanks. I know I've run into that problem before, but it must have been for a different reason.

Answer (score 2):

Because I have a pathological hatred of `while True` loops, I suggest this simplification of @kindall's answer: first, change `some_function()` so that it returns `False` on failure instead of throwing an exception. Then, use the following loop:

```
for cl in range(0, 10):
    while not some_function(cl): pass
```

If you can't (or don't want to) change `some_function()`, you could add a wrapper:

```
def exceptionless_function(arg):
    try:
        some_function(arg)
        return True
    except <known exceptions>:
        return False
```

**EDIT:** I added `<known exceptions>` above to indicate that the unqualified `except` clause should be avoided. If you don't *know* what types of exceptions you actually expect to catch, then simply calling the function again is *almost certainly* the wrong behavior in certain cases. For instance, OP mentions (in a comment) that there will be "an alert" if a timeout occurs while this function is being retried. If that alert happens to take the form of some kind of exception, then it will simply be ignored in the "catch-all" case!